# ABout "not in" in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with `SQL` `query`.

This is my code:

```
set @TimeComing=(Select TimeComing from Bill)
set @TimeCome= DATEPART(hour,@TimeComing)


if(@TimeCome>=22 and @TimeCome<=23)
  begin set @Bill=@ByDay set @Day=1 set @Hour=0 end
if(@TimeCome>=21 and @TimeCome<22)
  begin set @Bill=@ByHour set @Day=0 set @Hour=1 end
if(@TimeCome>=21 and @TimeCome<=23 and @TimeCome not in (@TimeCome>=21 and @TimeCome<22))
  begin set @Bill=@ByDay set @Day=1 set @Hour=0 end
```

As you see, i want to the 3rd condition - `TimeCome not in 21:00 and 22:00` to set `Bill=ByDay and Day=1`. Because of 2nd Condition is used this Parameter. But i have an error

> **"Incorrect syntax near '>'."**

Please help me this problem, thank you !

**Update**

This is my idea:

- If customer come in 21:00 and go in 22:00 (21:00 to 22:00) => @Bill=@ByHour.
- If customer come in 22:00 and go in 23:00 (22:00 to 23:00) => @Bill=@ByDay.
- If customer come in 21:00 and go in 23:00 (21:00 to 23:00) => @Bill=@ByDay.

Comment: `not in` or `in` check against collection provided in between paranthesis (or a query returning this collection), you probably want to check `between` operator

Comment: @Bartdude Yeah, i want to check TimeComing is not in (between '21:00:00' and '22:00:0') but i don't know how to used it. Thanks for helping !

Comment: @huycao:- What time you are exactly trying to check?

Comment: Sorry for my wrong, please read again.
Thanks for helping

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. why does @TimeCome stands for both `come` and `go`?

Comment: still doesn't make much sense. you can't use the same scalar variable to point to 2 different scalar values simultaneously. you must use either different columns in your table to specify the in and out times, or different rows. so you must use `@TimeIn` and `@TimeOut` to specify those values.

Comment: You have TimeCome. Where is TimeGo?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try this ie, your 3rd condition can be reduced down to this:</strike>

```
if(@TimeCome>=22 and @TimeCome<=23)
```

**EDIT:**

I think you dont need the 3rd condition at all. As 1st conditon is equivalent to the 3rd condition.

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
declare @flag = false
if(@TimeCome>=22 and @TimeCome<=23)
  begin set @Bill=@ByDay set @Day=1 set @Hour=0 end
if(@TimeCome>=21 and @TimeCome<22)
  begin set @Bill=@ByHour set @Day=0 set @Hour=1 set @flag = true end
if(@TimeCome>=21 and @TimeCome<=23 and (@flag = false))
  begin set @Bill=@ByDay set @Day=1 set @Hour=0 end
```

Comment: Actually, If I'm reading it correctly, shouldn't it just be `if @TimeCome = 23`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled:- Yes that makes a sense. But in that case it would go to the first condition. So I think the 3rd condition is not required at all. I wil wait for OP to comment!

Comment: Actually shouldn't be there a separate variable to capture exit time. Seems like @TimeCome is used to capture both entry and exist times.

Comment: @dcp1986:- Yes I agree that should be a case and rather it is a design flaw but I tried to give a solution as per the current design.

Comment: I try but it's not working :(.
Please read my question again. Thank you so much

Comment: @huycao:- Can you tell what is not working? Any errors whch you are getting?

Comment: @huycao:- Also to inform you that it seems like there is design flaw in your table structure. Ideally you should have two column in which you should store the value of `@timeIn` and `@timeOut` for a employee.

Answer (score 0):

This should be:

```
if(@TimeCome>=21 and @TimeCome<=23 and not (@TimeCome >= 21 and @TimeCome<22))
```

But it can be simplified:

```
if(@TimeCome>=22 and @TimeCome<=23)
```

But you have already have this as first `if` statement...

Comment: I try but it's not working :(.
Please read my question again. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set @Bill=@ByDay 
if(@TimeCome>=22 and @TimeCome<=23)
begin 
     select @Day=1, @Hour=0 
end
if(@TimeCome>=21 and @TimeCome<22)
begin 
       select @Day=0, @Hour=1 
end
```

**Explanation:**

- I've moved the `set @Bill=@ByDay` part outside of the condition since it's the same on every if.
- I've removed your third condition entirely, since the first condition is actually the same as what you said you want for the third one.
- Now, about the `IN` operator: it expects a comma delimited list of values, **not to be confused with a single variable that contains a comma delimited string!**, 
  so a correct use of it would be `and @TimeCome not in (21,22)`.
  Note that something like `and @TimeCome not in ('21,22')` would not return the results you want.

However, you don't seem to need it at all, as I've already written.

Comment: Thank you, but i'm wrong with my code, please read again
Thanks for helping !

Comment: I try but it's not working :(.
Please read my question again. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

First we cannot use directly where condition as you have done above in the 3rd statement, it will give error for **incorrect syntax**
You can use **not in** condition by two ways
1) select sub-query in not in condition, here by updating third statement to

```
       if(@TimeCome>=21 and @TimeCome<=23 and @TimeCome not in 
       (select  @TimeCome where @TimeCome >= 22)) begin set @Bill=@ByDay set @Day=1 set @Hour=0
        end
```

2) by setting values explicitly, here as below

```
      if(@TimeCome>=21 and @TimeCome<=23 and @TimeCome not in (@TimeCome1, @TimeCom2)
```